# Simple functions in queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return all the entries in my database that are fairly close to a given point. At the moment I am doing this (in the WHERE section):

```
OR (    
    (Addresses.Latitude IS NOT NULL)
    AND (Addresses.Longitude IS NOT NULL)
    AND ( Abs(Addresses.Latitude - @SearchInLat)  < 0.5)
    AND ( Abs(Addresses.Longitude - @SearchInLng) < 0.5)
)
```

I am doing manhattan distance rather than cartesian distance as my database has a large number of records, and calculating square roots is slow.

I'm pretty new to SQL databases, but I remember reading that it is considered very bad for efficiency to have functions inside SELECT procudures. Does this even apply for really simple functions such as taking the absolute value? Is something like:

```
OR (    
    (Addresses.Latitude IS NOT NULL)
    AND (Addresses.Longitude IS NOT NULL)
    AND ( (Addresses.Latitude - @SearchInLat)  < 0.5)
    AND ( (Addresses.Latitude - @SearchInLat)  > -0.5)
    AND ( (Addresses.Longitude - @SearchInLng) < 0.5)
    AND ( (Addresses.Longitude - @SearchInLng) > -0.5)
)
```

a better solution?

Comment: I think you meant to remove the ABS in the second example.

Comment: I did, thanks. I always read things twice before submitting them, but yet always seem to miss something!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is often not very efficient to have functions run on the data being returned - as in the case of your ABS.  I don't think you're in any trouble in this case, however.  You could avoid the use of the function by trying something like:

```
OR (    
    (Addresses.Latitude IS NOT NULL)
    AND (Addresses.Longitude IS NOT NULL)
    AND ( (Addresses.Latitude - @SearchInLat) BETWEEN -0.5 AND 0.5)
    AND ( (Addresses.Longitude - @SearchInLng) BETWEEN -0.5 AND 0.5)
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I did not know there was syntax like that. I tried doing `-0.5 < (Addresses.Latitude - @SearchInLat) < 0.5` but that wasn't valid.

Comment: Just note that this is slightly different. The original is `>` and `<`; `BETWEEN` is actually `>=` and `<=`...

Comment: It would be interesting to see if changing that to `Addresses.Latitude BETWEEN -0.5 - @SearchInLat AND 0.5 - @SearchInLat` is better since the end points only have to be calculated once.

Answer (score 2):

I think ABS and some builtin functions (like math functions) are very easily handled by the optimizer - others not so much (string and date operations).

In your particular case, I think you're OK with ABS.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Dealing with the optimizer is such a pain! A tiny change can send it off working in an entirely different way. I find it hard to work out what stuff helps and what stuff hinders.